# How to replicate NSArray memory semantics in a subclass

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, nsarray, automatic-ref-counting, autorelease

## Question

In my ARC project I have a class that manages objects, called `LazyMutableArray`. Some of the objects are actually nil, but users of my collection will never know about this; therefore I made it a subclass of `NSMutableArray`, and it tries to do "the same thing". In particular, objects are **retained when added**.

Now let's take a look at a memory behavior of other methods. It turns out that the `NSArray` destruction methods are **[documented by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-1000922-BABBFBGJ) to be an exception** to this rule, in that they *release*, not *autoreleased* object.

There is some debate as to whether the combination of `addObject:` + `objectAtIndex:` + array destruction is *documented by Apple to be never autoreleasing* or simply *happens to be in the examples I tested and in the example Apple includes*.

**How can I create in my subclass a method with exact same memory semantics?**

---

### Last update

After some thought, I've decided implementation based on `NSMutableArray` is more appropriate in this case compared to `NSPointerArray`. The new class, I should note, has the same `retain`/`autorelease` pair as the previous implementation.

Thanks to Rob Napier I see that no modification of my `objectAtIndex:` method would change this behavior, which answers my original question about this method.

On a practical level, several people said that any method can tackle an extra `retain`/`autorelease` pair for no reason; it's not reasonable to expect otherwise and not reasonable to try to find out which methods do this and which do not. It's been therefore a great learning opportunity for me on several levels.

Code (based on `NSMutableArray`) is available at GitHub:  [**implementation**](http://github.com/ilyannn/ODExplorer/blob/b62c0df18bdc50c590574c0a6a83c92ef2c901f8/0Dependencies/Helpers/ODLazyMutableArray.m), [**header**](http://github.com/ilyannn/ODExplorer/blob/b62c0df18bdc50c590574c0a6a83c92ef2c901f8/0Dependencies/Helpers/ODLazyMutableArray.h), [**test**](http://github.com/ilyannn/ODExplorer/blob/b62c0df18bdc50c590574c0a6a83c92ef2c901f8/0Dependencies/Helpers/HelpersTests.m) (that's `-testLazyMutableMemorySemantics`).
Thank you all for participating.

---

### Why I try to subclass `NSMutableArray`:

Subclassing foundation objects, I agree, is not always an appropriate solution. In tho case I have objects (in fact, OData resources), most of which have *subobjects*. The most natural class for **an array of subobjects** is obviously `NSArray`. Using a different class doesn't seem to make sense to me.

But for an OData collection this "array of sub objects", while, being an NSArray, must have a different implementation. Specifically, for a collection of 1000 elements, servers are encouraged to return collection in batches of (say)20, instead of all at once. If there is another pattern appropriate in this case, I'm all ears.

---

### Some more detail in how I found this

I unit test the hell out of this collection, and values can be put into array, read from the array, and so forth. So far, so good. However, I realized that **returning the object increases its retain count**.

How do I see it? Suppose I insert two objects into lazy array `lazy`, one held weakly, one held strongly (*see the code *). Then retain count of `weakSingleton` is, as expected, 1. But now I read element:

```
XCTAssertEqual(weakSingleton, lazy[0], @"Correct element storage"); // line B
```

And in the debugger I see the retain count go up to 2. Of course, `-retainCount` may give me wrong information, so let's try to destroy the reference in array by

```
lazy[0] = nil; // yep, does the right thing
XCTAssertNil(weakSingleton, @"Dropped by lazy array"); // line C <-- FAIL
```

indeed, we see that `weakSingleton` is not released.

By now you probably guess that it's not just a retain, it's an autoreleased retain — **putting an `@autorelease` around line B releases the `weakSingleton`**. The exact source of this pair is not obvious, but seems to come from `NSPointerArray -addPointer:` (and unfortunately not from ARC's `[[object retain] autorelease]`). However, I don't want to return an autoreleased object and make method semantics different from its superclass!

After all, *the method I'm overriding, NSMutableArray -objectAtIndex:`, doesn't do that*; the object it returns will dealloc immediately if an array is released, as noted in the Apple's example. That's what I want: *modify the method around line A so that the object it returns does not have an extra retain/autorelease pair*. I'm not sure the compiler should even let me do it :)

**Note 1** I could turn off ARC for a single file, but this would be my first non-ARC Objective-C code. And in any case the behavior may not some from ARC.

**Note 2** What the fuss? Well, in this case I could change my unit tests, but still, the fact is that by adding or deleting line B, I'm changing the result of unit test at line C.

In other words, the described behavior of my method `[LazyMutableArray -objectAtIndex]` is essentially that by *reading* an object at index 0, I'm actually *changing* the retain count of this object, which means I could encounter unexpected bugs.

**Note 3** Of course, if nothing is to be done about this, I'll document this behavior and move on; perhaps, this indeed should be considered an implementation detail, not to be included into tests.

---

### Relevant methods from implementation

```
    @implementation LazyMutableArray {
        NSPointerArray *_objects; 
        // Created lazily, only on -setCount:, insert/add object.
    }

    - (id)objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
        @synchronized(self) {
            if (index >= self.count) {
                return nil;
            }
            __weak id object = [_objects pointerAtIndex:index];
                if (object) {
                    return object;
                }
            }

        // otherwise do something else to compute a return value
        // but this branch is never called in this test
        [self.delegate array:self missingObjectAtIndex:index];

        @synchronized(self) {
            if (index >= self.count) {
                return nil;
            }
            __weak id object = [_objects pointerAtIndex:index];
            if (object) {
                return object;
            }
        }
        @throw([NSException exceptionWithName:NSObjectNotAvailableException
                               reason:@"Delegate was not able to provide a non-nil element to a lazy array"
                             userInfo:nil]);

    }

    - (void)createObjects {
        if (!_objects) {
            _objects = [NSPointerArray strongObjectsPointerArray];
        }
    }

    - (void)addObject:(id)anObject {
       [self createObjects];
       [_objects addPointer:(__bridge void*)anObject];
    }
```

---

### The complete test code:

```
// Insert two objects into lazy array, one held weakly, one held strongly.

NSMutableArray * lazy = [LazyMutableArray new];
id singleton = [NSMutableArray new];
[lazy addObject:singleton];

__weak id weakSingleton = singleton;
singleton = [NSMutableDictionary new];
[lazy addObject:singleton];

XCTAssertNotNil(weakSingleton, @"Held by lazy array");
XCTAssertTrue(lazy.count == 2, @"Cleaning and adding objects");

//    @autoreleasepool {
XCTAssertEqual(weakSingleton, lazy[0], @"Correct element storage");
XCTAssertEqual(singleton, lazy[1], @"Correct element storage");
//    }

lazy = nil;

XCTAssertNotNil(singleton, @"Not dropped by lazy array");
XCTAssertNil(weakSingleton, @"Dropped by lazy array");
```

The last line **fails**, but it succeeds if I change first line to `lazy = [NSMutableArray new]` **or** if I uncomment `@autoreleasepool`.

Comment: Under ARC, locals are strong.

Comment: Because they seem to be inserted by ARC in a way which is non-obvious to me. Since retains and autoreleases still exist and **break my unit tests** I should learn more.

Comment: Perhaps the pointer array is withholding `-release`'ing nil elements.  Call `-[NSPointerArray compact]` before the nil check.

Comment: `return [[objectIOwn retain] autorelease];` is a valid (even recommended) pattern to make sure that the caller has a chance to retain the returned object in case owner is deallocated in the middle of the access. It looks to me like ARC is using that pattern. This is a good thing.

Comment: Your `__weak id weakSingleton` doesn't really prove anything is wrong. A weak reference just means _that_ reference isn't owning. Another object, like an array, can still get a strong reference _via_ that weak ref. Again, expected behavior.

Comment: valid -- Yup, as a rule. But I'd like to create a method with **exact semantics** of `[NSArray -objectAtIndex:]`. Without ARC, I could return simply `object`. Is it possible under ARC?

Comment: Ja, `__attribute__((ns_returns_not_retained))` might kick the compiler into listening to you.

Comment: If I delete line B, the `weakSingleton` is released. Since **accessing an object must not change its internal state** I consider this behavior of my method unacceptable.

Comment: What do you mean "make the caller remember this"? The caller doesn't need to know anything about the retain count and autoreleases on the object (especially under ARC). What exactly are you unit testing that this breaks?

Comment: I'm unit testing the fact that object is released. As I explain, unit test at line C fails iff line B is present. Historically, in fact, I wrote the line C first and it passed, *until I added another unit test*.

Comment: @CodaFi, perhaps you could write an answer?

Comment: Did that happen to work?

Comment: No, it says I didn't match attribute on, ironically, [NSArray -objectAtIndex:] -- I subclass `NSMutableArray`. But we could continue this conversation on an answer.

Comment: Seems to me you're trying to unit test an implementation detail that the caller shouldn't rely on anyway.

Comment: How did you implement addObject:? I can't get this behavior to reproduce in a simple test case. (Specifically, I'm not seeing the objects dealloc if you add the autoreleasepool either)

Comment: @Kevin, but it's documented by Apple, see the link!

Comment: Your doc link _does not_ say that `objectAtIndex:` won't use `retain`/`autorelease`. It says that the object is sent `release` when either it's _removed_ from the collection or the collection itself is destroyed.

Comment: Well, it does say *If the collection was the only owner of the removed object, the removed object (heisenObject in the example ) is then immediately deallocated.*, using specifically an example with previous `objectAtIndex:`. This is not consistent with  `objectAtIndex:` using `retain`/`autorelease`. It also doesn't seem consistent with `addObject` doing an extra `retain`/`autorelease`, which seems to be the case for `NSPointerArray`.

Comment: You mean "heisenObject *could* now be invalid"? Or "*If the collection was the only owner of the removed object*, the removed object (heisenObject in the example ) is then immediately deallocated"? If the object was autoreleased anywhere in that autorelease pool, it won't magically be deallocated by removing it from an `NSArray`.

Comment: Anyway, you can always disable arc for that particular file (`-fno-objc-arc`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would not make this subclass. This is exactly what `NSPointerArray` is for. Wrapping that into an `NSArray` obscures important details that this approach can break. For example, what is the correct behavior for `[NSArray arrayWithArray:lazyMutableArray]` if `lazyMutableArray` includes NULLs? Algorithms that assume that `NSArray` can never include NULL need to be wary of the fact that this one can. It's true that you can get similar issues treating a non-retaining `CFArray` as an `NSArray`; I speak from experience that this is exactly why this kind of subclass can be very dangerous (and why I stopped doing that years ago). Don't create a subclass that cannot be used in every case that its superclass can be used ([LSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)).

If you have a collection with new semantics, I would subclass it from `NSObject`, and have it conform to `<NSFastEnumeration>`. See how `NSPointerArray` is not a subclass of `NSArray`. This was not an accident. Faced with the same problem, note the direction Apple chose.

> By now you probably guess that it's not just a retain, it's an autoreleased retain — putting an @autorelease around line B releases the weakSingleton. This seems to be because line A under ARC translates to [[object retain] autorelease]. However, I don't want to return an autoreleased object and make caller remember this!

The caller should never assume anything else. The caller is *never* free to assume that a method does not add balanced autoreleases. If a caller wants the autorelease pool to drain, that is their responsibility.

All that said, there is some benefit to avoiding an extra autorelease if it's not required, and it's an interesting learning opportunity.

I would start by reducing this code to the simplest form, without your subclass at all. Just explore how `NSPointerArray` works:

```
__weak id weakobject;
@autoreleasepool
{
  NSPointerArray *parray = [NSPointerArray strongObjectsPointerArray];
  {
    id object = [NSObject new];
    [parray addPointer:(__bridge void*)object];
    weakobject = object;
  }
  parray = nil;
}
NSAssert(!weakobject, @"weakobject still exists");
```

My structure here (such as the extra nesting block) is designed to try to avoid accidentally creating strong references I don't mean to make.

In my experiments, this fails without the autoreleasepool and succeeds with it. That indicates that the extra retain/autorelease is being added around or by the call to `addPointer:`, not by ARC modifying your interface.

If you're not using this implementation for `addObject:`, I'd be interested in digging deeper. It is an interesting question, even if I don't believe you should be subclassing this way.

Comment: Re:`[NSArray arrayWithArray:lazyMutableArray]`, the correct behavior is to get an array without nulls. That is, `(id)objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index` is expected to not return nil. When it encounters `nil` it calls the delegate; it's not possible to create a `LazyMutableArray` without a delegate. Delegate *must* fill in the missing element; for my example with OData it insert an empty resource *and* makes a server request. I agree an explicit exception in necessary for when the delegate doesn't fulfill its duties; this will be added.

Comment: Seriously, I wouldn't be subclassing `NSMutableArray` if it had different semantics; mine only differs in *implementation*.

Comment: Re: *The caller is never free to assume that a method does not add balanced autoreleases.* Here's the problem: this behavior (full release) is **explicitly documented** by Apple. Obviously, my app won't be destroyed by this detail; I'll drain autorelease poll if I really need to and chances of somebody else using my class are... slim. However, this is a very **interesting mental exercise**.

Comment: Re: `NSAssert(!weakobject,` ... Indeed, I completed the tests... seems you're right. In that case do you think there is anything to be done, except stop using `NSPointerArray`?

Comment: You may want to consider using Apple's existing mutable array proxy that already achieves most of what you're describing here. See the docs for `[NSKeyValueCoding mutableArrayValueForKey:]`. This will return a proxy object that forwards all its accesses to KVC methods (which you can then implement lazily). (This may be more than is required, but it's useful to know it exists.) Beyond that, I would consider holding your data in an NSDictionary (index->id) rather than an NSPointerArray. I believe the values from NSDictionary will give you an implementation closer to NSArray.

Comment: Regarding the documentation, you are only guaranteed that no additional *net* retains are placed on an object. You are never in Cocoa promised that there will be no temporary (balanced w/ autorelease) retains. Apple is free to change the number of temporary retains at any time.

Comment: Search for "proxy" in this doc for more on the existing mutable collection proxies: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/AccessorConventions.html

Comment: Ok, I've also tried changing implementation from pointer array to `NSMutableArray` - same thing with autorelease. I'm going to document it as-is and move on. Re:proxy, no, the delegate is there only to fill in missing elements, so I'm not sure proxy is relevant here. I've put the code on Github, links will be in the answer in a few minutes, if you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to elaborate on why I said this "looks a lot like a homework assignment." This will likely earn me many down votes, but it will also server as a good learning case for others who later find this question.

Subclassing `NSMutableArray` not a goal of a program. It is a means to achieve something else. If I were to venture a guess, I expect you were trying to create an array that lazily creates the object when they are accessed. There are better ways to do this without dealing with memory management yourself.

Here's an example of how I would implement a lazy loading array.

```
@interface LazyMutableArray : NSMutableArray
- (id)initWithCreator:(id(^)(int))creator;
@end

@interface LazyMutableArray ( ) 
@property (nonatomic, copy) id (^creator)(int);
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger highestSet;
@end

@implementation LazyMutableArray

- (id)initWithCreator:(id(^)(int))creator
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.highestSet = NSNotFound;
        self.creator = creator;
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    id obj = nil;
    if ((index < self.highestSet) && (self.highestSet != NSNotFound)) {
        obj = [super objectAtIndex:index];
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
            obj = self.creator(index);
            [super replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:obj];
        }
    } else {
        if (self.highestSet == NSNotFound) {
            self.highestSet = 0;
        }
        while (self.highestSet < index) {
            [super add:[NSNull null]];
            self.highestSet += 1;
        }
        obj = self.creator(index);
        [super add:obj];
        self.highestSet += 1;
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Fair Warning: I'm not compiling or syntax checking any of this code. It probably has a few bugs in it, but it should generally work. Additionally, this implementation is missing an implementation of `add:`, `count`, `removeObjectAtIndex:`, `insertObject:atIndex:`, and possibly `replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:`. What I show here is just to get you started.

Comment: Sure, added code. I'm not sure about that bridge cast indeed, but the code works perfectly with autorelease pool. I do appreciate you are trying to help, but, again, all of my methods are implemented and tested, so it's not about correctness, it's about some semantics of ARC.